# API for information about Brazilian cities/states

Tags: api, census, brazil

I can already find data about Brazilian cities/states (e.g. population, localization, crime rates etc...), on some websites such as the [government's open data portal](http://dados.gov.br/dataset/search?tags=finan%C3%A7as&tags=IBGE) and [census data](ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Censos/Censo_Demografico_2010/) (which unfortunately is a mess).

Is there any API for this information, that would make it easier to query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the Brazilian Community CKAN instance http://br.ckan.net/dataset and the [Brazilian Government's official Data Portal (CKAN-powered)](http://dados.gov.br/) which you link to, have APIs.

There's also the World Bank API: http://data.worldbank.org/

Answer (score 2):

You could use [dbpedia](http://live.dbpedia.org/) and its [sparql endpoint](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql) for this. The following SPARQL query would return all metrics except crime rates, [you asked for](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20dbo%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20dbr%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbp%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A?city%20rdf%3atype%20dbo%3aCity%20.%20%0D%0A?city%20foaf%3aisPrimaryTopicOf%20?wikipediaPage%20.%0D%0A?city%20dbo%3acountry%20dbr%3aBrazil%20.%0D%0A?city%20rdfs%3alabel%20?cityLabel%20.%0D%0A?city%20dbp%3apopulationTotal%20?population%20.%0D%0A?city%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long%3E%20?longitude%20.%0D%0A?city%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long%3E%20?latitude%20.%0D%0A%7D&should-sponge=&format=text/html&timeout=0&debug=on).

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT * WHERE { 
?city rdf:type dbo:City . 
?city foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikipediaPage .
?city dbo:country dbr:Brazil .
?city rdfs:label ?cityLabel .
?city dbp:populationTotal ?population .
?city <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long> ?longitude .
?city <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long> ?latitude .
}
```

All the attributes that are mentioned in for example the dbpedia entry of [Sao Paolo](http://live.dbpedia.org/page/S%C3%A3o_Paulo) are available through sparql queries.